# STM32WB : Is it possible to wakeup standby mode via BLE?

Tags: stm32, wakeup, standby

I am starting a project using STM32WB MCU. I would like to minimize the power consumption while in sleep, but able to wake it up via BLE command.
From the document AN5071([STM32WB ultra-low-power features overview](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an5071-stm32wb-series-microcontrollers-ultralowpower-features-overview-stmicroelectronics.pdf)) it says "Wakeup from this mode can also be performed by the Radio sub-system." But I didn't found any further description or example about the 'Radio sub-system'. Does the 'Radio sub-system' is same as BLE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got reply from ST employee saying it depends on the model. For STM32WB55 it's not possible to enter standby mode with RF active. Check [AN5289](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00598033-building-wireless-applications-with-stm32wb-series-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf).
But for STM32WB15 it is possible. Reference the BLE_HeartRate example in STM32CubeWB example.

Answer (score 1):

The only radio in that part is a bluetooth radio, so yes "Radio sub-system" means "BLE subsystem".

For more details you will have to read the reference manual:

- [RM0471 for STM32WB50CG/30CE](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0471-multiprotocol-wireless-32bit-mcu-armbased-cortexm4-with-fpu-bluetooth-low-energy-or-802154-radio-solution-stmicroelectronics.pdf)
- [RM0478 for STM32WB10CC](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0478-multiprotocol-wireless-32bit-mcu-armbased-cortexm4-with-fpu-bluetooth-53-radio-solution-stmicroelectronics.pdf)
- [RM0473 for STM32WB15CC](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0473-multiprotocol-wireless-32bit-mcu-armbased-cortexm4-with-fpu-bluetooth-53-radio-solution-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the info. On a second thought.... it seems pointless to enter standby mode for CPU1 while CPU2 runs BLE stack. Because BLE might cost several mA power consumption, but standby mode only saves several uA compare to stop modes.

Comment: @Orange: Can you please accept the answer with the tick mark on the left?

Comment: I got an official reply from ST community....